# referencing a sheet which has a formula inside

Tags: excel, excel-formula, reference, formula

I have a formula in Sheet2 which is following:

```
=((COUNTIF((INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(J4);COLUMN(J4))&":J"& 
(MIN(IF(A4:A107="";ROW(A4:A107))))));" 
<>"&""))-1)/((COUNTIF((INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(J4);COLUMN(J4))&":J"& 
(MIN(IF(A4:A107="";ROW(A4:A107))))));"<>0"))-1)
```

I want to write this formula to my Sheet1 and calculate it in Sheet1 instead of in Sheet2. I know that i need to reference Sheet2 but could not do correctly until now.

**EDIT**
I tried adding Sheet2! before the cells as below but this does not give me the same result with the above formula

```
=((COUNTIF((INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(Sheet2!J4);COLUMN(Sheet2!J4))&":J"& 
 (MIN(IF(Sheet2!A4:A107="";ROW(Sheet2!A4:A107))))));" 
 <>"&""))-1)/((COUNTIF((INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(Sheet2!J4);
COLUMN(Sheet2!J4))&":J"& (MIN(IF(Sheet2!A4:A107="";ROW(Sheet2!A4:A107))))));"<>0"))-1)
```

How can i solve this referencing issue correcty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On general level you need to add the sheet name in the cell address with `=<sheetname>!<cell>`, 
like this `=Sheet2!A1`.

In your case you need to change all the cell/range references to refer to Sheet2, so something like `INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&ADDRESS(...))`, `ROW(Sheet2!J4)` and `COLUMN(Sheet2!J4)`.

Comment: I know this but it does not deliver me the same result, so i edited the question, this -1 part probably causes problem

Comment: It seems like an overly complicated formula so I'm trying to break it down, correct me if I'm mistaken with what you're trying to do.
To me it seems you use `ROW(<cell>)` and `COLUMN(<cell>)`, feed their result to `ADDRESS(row;col)` which gives you the string representation of the cell you used, which you then pass to `INDIRECT(text)` to get back the cell reference. It looks like this could be completely replaced with just the cell.

Comment: Regardless of my previous comment, you seem to be missing something in the first `COUNTIF()` condition, it's just `" <>"&""` whereas the second is `"<>0"`

Comment: second one does something else thats why. My formula works exactly how i find but when i reference it, it does not work correct

Comment: Yea, I broke it down just to test what each step gives and the only thing I can find that might cause issues is the `MIN(IF(A4:A107="";ROW(A4:A107)))` as it might return 0 which is not a valid cell row. Also, the `INDIRECT()` call might need to be prepended with the sheet name too, otherwise it'll refer to the current sheet. If it isn't any of these I'm out of ideas :|

Comment: i mean, it works inside Sheet2. Does not work when i reference Sheet" in Sheet1

Comment: Is the formula on your edit exactly the one you have on Sheet1?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169844/discussion-between-jussiv-and-soru-soravic).